# Rails Webpacker compile error on Production enviorment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

## env

```
Rails 6.0.0
Ruby 2.6.0
Amazon Linux2
```

## What

[image]

When I deploy my rails app this error happen

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application in /home/web/www/eloop-regular/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
```

### 1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.

my config/webpacker.yml contains

```
production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: true

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

### 2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.

I run

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails webpacker:compile
```

### 3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.

in development environment webpacker works correctly.

### 4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.

manifest.json is created

Answer (score 28):

I have the same issue when I run pre-built rails 6 app.Found out it is because of Webpack version inconsistency in yarn.lock file. 
Then when I run

`yarn add @rails/webpacker`

`bundle update webpacker`

as found in this [comment](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1494#issuecomment-388305305) , issue's solved.

Comment: ```yarn add @rails/webpacker``` helped me to solve the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Remove Webpacker:

```
rm -rf bin/webpack*
```

Install Webpacker:

```
rails webpacker:install
```

Compile by Webpacker in `production` mode:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails webpacker:compile
```

<kbd>[About this](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1494#issuecomment-388308053)</kbd>

Comment: Should the command to do webpacker:compile be run on heroku using the heroku bash command?

Comment: @Obromios May be, try it there

Comment: That did not work. Eventually I solved it by removing my stylesheet_pack_tag from application.html, as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59161189/rails-webpacker-4-2-cant-find-application-in-app-public-packs-manifest-json-h/59162932#59162932. I could do this as I was not using webpacker to compile the apps css files.

Answer (score 3):

I'd the same problem. Just run in development environment:

```
rails webpacker:install
```

If you use Docker, run:

```
docker exec rails-app-name rails webpacker:install
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `manifest.json` does not exist in your filesystem create it with `rake assets:precompile`.

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was to replace
`<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`
with `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`
In the **application.html.erb** file