# Webpacker can't find application.js with Rails 6.1 and Devise module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, devise, yarnpkg

I forked an existing rails project, added `devise` to my Gemfile, and then installed it:

```
$ rails generate devise:install
$ rails generate devise User
$ rails db:migrate
```

After the initial migration, I tried to go to  http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up but it generates a 500 error with the following information:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application.js in /home/lucky/project/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
}
```

As you can see, my manifest appears to be empty above. Thats because the directory `/home/lucky/project/public/packs` doesn't exist. The rails project I'm working with was working fine before adding devise (I'm following a [tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/using-devise-in-your-ruby-on-rails-application-a-step-by-step-guide-m92i3y5s)).

I'm unfamiliar with webpack. I've tried a couple of [hints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59370748/9727704) to no avail. I'd like to know why this directory is needed before I start mucking up my project structure. How do I fix this?

### EDIT

(1) There is a packs directory under `app/javascript`

(2) `config/webpacker.yml` seems to be aware of this location:

[snip]

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  webpack_compile_output: true
```

[/snip]

(3) There is no `manifest.json` anywhere in the app directory structure.

Comment: please update with the development block from webpacker.yml.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install webpacker. Stop the server and run

```
rails webpacker:install
```

This will create the dependencies you are missing.